# How to format output from Azure CLI

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

When I execute

```bash
az ad sp list --display-name Shazoo --query "[].appId"
```

the output is

> [
>   "2dda03c9-5d9b-4772-a666-c870a8c933c9"
> ]

which works for copy/paste purposes. However, when I store it in a variable and try to retrieve it, it seems that I'm not obtaining an array (containing a single element) but rather a string (consisting of three lines).

```bash
$AppId = az ad sp list --display-name Shazoo --query "[].appId"
```

If I print `$AppId[0]` to the console, I see the opening bracket. Printing `$AppId[1]` produces the GUID but includes the leading spaces and surrounding quotation marks.

Not sure if it's a Azure CLI issue (the output provided) or if it's PowerShell issue (the output rendered).

What would be a good way to research it further?

(I sense it's well-documented but using keywords I'm ignorant of. Hence, I'm not asking *how to*, rather *how to find the actual how-to*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're capturing the *textual output* (i.e. stdout) of the `az` command line into `$AppId`.

Since it's in json format, if you want to be able to work with it as in-memory objects instead you can simply pipe it into `ConvertFrom-Json` - e.g.

```
$stdout = az ad sp list --display-name Shazoo --query "[].appId"
$AppIds = $stdout | ConvertFrom-Json
$AppId = $AppIds[0]
```

(you can simplify these steps into a single pipeline if you prefer - I've left it expanded here for clarity)

That works with more complex json output as well which might be useful if, for example, you don't use the `--query` to pre-filter the output, although you might want to also add the [`--output json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli#json-output-format) parameter onto the call to `az` to ensure it comes back in the right format...

Comment: I took the liberty to "connect" your sample with @Paolo to make this question perfectly attended to. Feel free to rollback if you dislike people horsing around your contribution.  :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten np - i've just flagged it in the text so I don't get confused if I ever come back to read this and the comments have gone and I wonder why I don't remember writing that part :-)

Comment: @KonradViltersten please don't do that, there's no point in mixing answers like this. let future visitors credit whichever answer they deem useful

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario you should use the `tsv` output:

```
$AppId = $(az ad sp list --display-name Shazoo --query "[].appId" --output tsv)
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli for more information.

Comment: Yes, in this particular case, that's actually working. However. as soon as I fetch more than a single property, the problem reemerges. I see that my sensation of dealing with the rendered string output was about right. What do you think of the approach suggested by @mclayton above? It feel as a more scalable/extrapoleable approach to objectify the actual output instead of dealing with the rendered version. I see one drawback - the syntax may get clunky very quickly.

Comment: @KonradViltersten well, it depends on what data you are expecting. Are you expecting JSON? Use `json` output. Are you expecting a single value? Use `tsv` output.

Comment: I truly hate that rare situation when two answers are perfect, can't be merged and I only have one greeny checky thingy... Truly hate...   :(